# Work Item Description does not get value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I 'm using below code to send `WorkItem` to `tfs` programmatically

```
        const String username = "user";
        const String password = "123";

        Uri url = new Uri("myurl");

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
        nc.UserName = username;
        nc.Password = password;
        TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, nc);
        coll.EnsureAuthenticated();

        WorkItemStore workItemStore = coll.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project teamproject = workItemStore.Projects["Service"];
        WorkItemType workItemType = teamproject.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];

        WorkItem wi = new WorkItem(workItemType);

        wi.Title = "thi has sent from Code";
        wi.Description = "please remove this work Item";
        wi.Tags = "c#";

        wi.Save();
```

But when I check a `workItem` it just have Title and there is nothing in Description .
I try to set Description Like below but it did not work.

```
      wi.Fields[CoreField.Description].Value = "<p>hey hey</p> ";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "**Bug**" the field is not "**Description**". It should be "**STEP TO REPRODUCE**" just as the image showed above.

Set like below to add the ReproSteps for bug:

```
wi.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps"].Value = "set value here";
```